# Axios Interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios

In my react app, i use axios interceptor to refresh auth token. In my app, i use context and use reducre. there will be seprate files for context and reducer like this,

```
--Context
    -AuthContext.js
    -AuthReducer.js
    -AuthState.js
```

In AuthState.js there will be all api call.
There will be sperate file for the react component.

Therefore where should i place axios interceptor. should i place in AuthState.js where i make api call, or in React component files.

In some tutorial they add to the main landing page.. but for me i can't because landing page is public

Comment: I will create a separate file for axios, and use axios instance, so I only add the interceptor only this instance. for refreshing api call, you can just have a small function sitting in the same file, or like in redux, put it in an action file